# Calling user defined functions with Create Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following function

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetIdentity() RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (IDENT_CURRENT('tblTempPo'))
END
GO
```

I need to call it with create table

```
create table tblTempPo
(
ID int null,
 BrickVolume AS
              (
              GetIdentity() 
              )
)
```

I'm getting the error

> 'GetIdentity' is not a recognized built-in function name.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `dbo` (or whatever the schema name is) to properly call the function:

```
create table tblTempPo
(
    ID int null,
    BrickVolume AS(dbo.GetIdentity())
)
```

Although, for your example to work, you'd want to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblTempPo
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    AnotherField VARCHAR(10),
    BrickVolume AS (dbo.GetIdentity())
)
GO

INSERT INTO tblTempPo VALUES('a')
INSERT INTO tblTempPo VALUES('b')
INSERT INTO tblTempPo VALUES('c')
SELECT * FROM tblTempPo
```

The `SELECT` statement will yield the results:

```
ID     AnotherField     BrickVolume
-----------------------------------
 1          a               3
 2          b               3
 3          c               3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call user defined function with its schema name, like:

```
dbo.GetIdentity()
```